# Kibana filter regex with dash

Tags: regex, filter, kibana

In Kibana, I want to filter for a regex query that contains a dash.

The following picture shows the possible values I want to filter. I want all values that match `egov_dev_ge-online_vaem` but not `egov_dev_ge-online_wba`. 
So I tried it with the regex query `egov_dev_ge-online_vaem`, but kibana seems to have a problem with the dash. When I use the filter `egov_dev_ge`, it finds the values that are highlighted in orange below. But as soon as I use `egov_dev_ge-` it finds no results. Does the dash have a special meaning to Kibana? Are there any ways to escape the dash?

[image]

Comment: Try escaping the dash like this: \-

Comment: Escaping doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your filter requires a special character or punctuation, it will not work because the ElasticSearch standard analyzer throws out punctuation, and won't index it.

So the index sees:

```
egov dev ge online vaem 
egov dev ge online wba
// notice no underscores (_) or hyphens (-)
```

See this message on the elastic.co discussion page [Search for special characters inside the message](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-for-special-characters-inside-the-message/106553/2)

Comment: This is how AWS's Kibana is configured by default. You can't search within any field for a value that contains _ or -. Horrible!